# Arrow function and filter method not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**This is What the questions asking for.**

Inside the evens function use the built in filter method to filter over the array called numbers and return a new array with only the even numbers. Make sure to use the arrow function combined with the filter method.

- The numbers variable will be changed during tests.
- Should use arrow function
- Should use filter method

**This is what I have to use to answer the question.**

```
var numbers = "TBD";
var evens = () => {
          //Your code here
        }
```

Comment: Lambda functions are - > not => so () - > {... code...}

Comment: @StuartBrand what language are you talking about? in JS it is `=>`

Comment: SO is not there to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. `numbers` is an array of numbers and then to get the even ones in even call the `filter` function on the array and supply it with an arrow function that return true if the number is divisible by 2 - thus even.

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
var evens = numbers.filter(n => n % 2 == 0)
```

To use the exact code you provided where `evens` will  be a function that returns the even numbers:

```
var evens = () => {
          return numbers.filter(n => n % 2 == 0);
        }
```

Comment: That didn't work, I have to use the code that was provided :(

Comment: Does `evens` need to be a function that return the even numbers from `numbers`?

Comment: Yes it does, because I had it the way you set it up before but it didn't work :/